# Pandas df.mask isnull getting too many arguments error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with three ID columns. I need to select one of those three columns as the final ID for a later merge.

If one of the ID fields is in another list of IDs, I need to use that one, otherwise I need to choose between the other two.

```
pull = pd.merge(pull, knownids, left_on='id3', right_on='mainid', how='left')
pull['id3'] = pull['id3'].mask(pull['mainid'].isnull, 0)
```

The idea is I want to replace anything in the 'id3' column with 0 if the merged id is empty.

however, I get an error: TypeError: isnull() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I'm not sure where this other positional argument is coming from. Any ideas?

Comment: Typo? isnull() with paranthesises.

Comment: pull['id3'] = pull['id3'].mask(pull['mainid'].isnull(), 0)

Comment: That works but it seems wrong. In my head it's the difference between passing a callable and a called, if that makes any sense.

Comment: "The called" is a Series of True/False, which `mask` uses to perform its replacement operation. Some functions expects a callable, some functions expect the values (possibly the result returned by another callable).